# Multiple $this attribute for re-usable class in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I came across this simple star rating system with font awesome. I have a problem though. In a page where there are multiple star blocks for rating they all get called at the same time. How can I prevent this behavior and have only the intended block to apply the clicked stars?

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/VGx6r/

HTML

```
<div class="star-rating"> 
  <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="1"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="2"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="3"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="4"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="5"></span>
  <input type="hidden" name="whatever" class="rating-value" value="3">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.star-rating {
  line-height:32px;
  font-size:1.25em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var $star_rating = $('.star-rating .fa');

var SetRatingStar = function() {
  return $star_rating.each(function() {
    if (parseInt($star_rating.siblings('input.rating-value').val()) >= parseInt($(this).data('rating'))) {
      return $(this).removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');
    } else {
      return $(this).removeClass('fa-star').addClass('fa-star-o');
    }
  });
};

$star_rating.on('click', function() {
  $star_rating.siblings('input.rating-value').val($(this).data('rating'));
  return SetRatingStar();
});

SetRatingStar();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of this:

`var $star_rating = $('.star-rating .fa');`

It is applying the function to every star-rating class.

You would need to modify that selector to specify which one to change. You could pass the element into `setStarRating`

Example:

`return SetStarRating($(this));`

and then use that in the `SetRatingStar` method

In response to your comment. I'm feeling generous so here you go:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bP7m/)

Comment: Ok I see. Thx. I'm really sweating with this though. Would you be able to fix it for me? I just dont think I can work it out on my own even though you exposed the culprit :-/

Comment: added fiddle to answer

Comment: Brilliant! Very kind of you to set it up for me. I just added the orginal fiddle to my post. Cheers!